# "Send To Messenger" page scoped user id, different to messenger id

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

When using the "Send To Messenger" plugin, the response received is:

```
    {
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "410441912660258",
            "time": 1506529761355,
            "messaging": [
                {
                    "recipient": {
                        "id": "410441912660258"
                    },
                    "timestamp": 1506529761355,
                    "sender": {
                        "id": "1388094137927363"
                    },
                    "optin": {
                        "ref": "login"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
```

However, when I interact with Messenger using the same Messenger Account, Facebook sends:

```
    {
    "originalRequest": {
        "source": "facebook",
        "data": {
            "sender": {
                "id": "1271682282961502"
            },
            "recipient": {
                "id": "1818762375111057"
            },
            "message": {
                "mid": "mid.$cAAZ2J6JWBDZk9XGKQVexCxoKu27Y",
                "text": "hi",
                "seq": 17289
            },
            "timestamp": 1506529788481
        }
    }
    }
```

Note that, despite using the same Messenger account, the sender/recipient IDs are different. So I can't match any users up from the Messenger Chat vs the Send To Messenger button.

I believe this is because the "Send To Messenger" button is using the Page Scoped User ID of the relevant Facebook Page, instead of the Facebook App.  Is there any way to match these two IDs or, to tell the Send To Messenger button to use the APP ID instead of the Page ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ID matching API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching